# Holomorphic automorphism of strictly psudo-convex domain smooth on boundary

Tags: cv.complex-variables, dg.differential-geometry

I am wondering if anything is known about this.  I couldn't find anything in the literature.

In '74 C. Fefferman published a solution to the following problem.
Let $\sigma:D\rightarrow D$ be an automorphism of a strictly pseudoconvex domanain $D\subset\mathbb{C}^n$.  Then $\sigma$ extends to a smooth map $\sigma:\overline{D}\rightarrow\overline{D}$.

My question: Is anything known about this problem for a strictly pseudoconvex domain
$D\subset M$ in a complex manifold $M$?

I have an idea of how to prove it for $K_M >0$, i.e. positive canonical bundle.  Fefferman's approach used the Bergman metric.  The Bergman metric is nondegenerate for more general domains only if $K_M$ is very ample, which is too strong an assumption to be very interesting.